# Multiple subdomains in one container

Tags: laravel, docker, containers, cloud, devops

Is it possible to have one container but different subdomains or ENV_VARIABLES?

I have a multi-tenant laravel school management application that uses multiple databases. Each school connects to a database of it's own. I want to use one container, since the schools share the same codebase, but connect to different databases through the DB_DATABASE env_variable.

Comment: You can have different env variables but they must be UNIQUE, so `DB_HOST` can only be used one, so you should define others with similar names like `DB_HOST_PRIMARY`, `DB_HOST_CUSTOMERS`, etc.

Comment: Question: how did you implement multi-tenant, because there are packages out there that handle this use case, maybe a subdomain per tenant and then find it's database through the subdomain.